# design to access a variable from a nested class

Tags: c++, oop

Basically, I have the following structure:

```
class A { 
    const double x;
    class B { 
        void f() { /* need access to x */ }
    };
};
```

What's the right way to do it? I've considered adding a reference to the `A`-parent inside `B` class, but then I can't use default constructor for `B`.
Is there a better way, or design?

Comment: That's not a parent class, it's a nested class, `B` doesn't know anything about `A` so your only way to get `x` is through an `A` object member.

Comment: could x be static?

Comment: @GillBates, thanks for the correction - yes, of course

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - thanks, I guess, I was hoping for a cleaner way, but making it static is definitely a solution

Comment: If B needs to know about a member of an A, the only way is for it to have a pointer or reference to an A or to the member itself. Just because the class is defined within A doesn't mean that it will be associated with any particular A object when it is constructed.

Comment: @MarkRansom, right. I don't want to go that way, because then I need to make a constructor for B to pass a reference or a pointer, and construct B-objects explicitly. So I'll try to go with the static x;

Comment: That sounds like a very brittle design decision, the kind I'd hate to inherit. I hope you know what you're doing!

Comment: Really, having the declaration of B sitting inside A is a red herring. It's the same problem if A and B are declared separately. - Instances of A and B don't magically know anything about each other. You the developer have to connect them in whatever way makes sense, whether that be pointers, references, passing parameters, statics, etc.

Comment: @LazyCat, how do you construct `B`'s non explicitly?

Comment: @StoryTeller usual way: `B b1, b2, b3` inside A

Comment: @LazyCat defining variables is very explicit. Either way, the `B` c'tor is called as part of constructing `A`.

Comment: @StoryTeller what's your point? It could also be `B bees[256]`

Comment: @LazyCat My point is that neither is less explicit given the C++ object model.

Answer (score 0):

One option

```
   class A {
    public:
    int x;
    class B {
        public:
        void foo(int x) {
            cout << x;
        }
    };
    B b;
    void foo() {
        b.foo(x);
    }
};

int main() {
    A temp;
    temp.x = 5;
    temp.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I definitely want to keep foo internal to B. I guess, that's partially where the structural issue is: I want to to foo() to be local to B and use non-local information about x at the same time.

Comment: And I'm not sure how you can accomplish that. Also I finished this up into a full example

Comment: Assuming that fits your use case then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can go away with your first attempt and use a cast operator for `A` so that you don't have anymore to care about the constructor of `B`:

```
struct A { 
    struct B {
        B(A &a): a{a} {}
        void f() { a.x; }
    private:
        A &a;
    };

    explicit operator B() {
        return B{*this};
    }

private:
    friend class B;
    const double x{0};
 };

 int main() {
     A a;
     A::B b = a;
 }
```

Be aware that you **must** assure that the lifetime of `a` overcomes the one of `b`. Otherwise you'll fall down on a dangling pointer somewhere sooner or later.